# show notification method change in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I found this method on vogella website. they called this method from the onclick attribute of a button in main.xml file. Can anyone tell, how to change this method to use without calling View?

```
public void createNotification(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("content").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original_logo)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

This is the link for the place which i got this method

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

I tried this way. This is the edited version of above method by me

```
public void createNotification(String title,String content) {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original_logo)`enter code here`
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

Then i tried to call this edited method as below.

```
try {

        Double inc_val = Double.parseDouble(display_incamo.getText().toString());
        Double exp_val = Double.parseDouble(display_expamo.getText().toString());
        if(inc_val<exp_val){
            createNotification("Expenses are High","Your expenses are almost higher than income");
        }else{
            createNotification("Expenses are Low","Keep it up Buddy!!!");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But then notification isn't pop up.

Comment: just remove the view parameter and call createNotification(); from where ever you need. You may add the message as a string parameter.

Comment: I tried that way, But there is an error rahul.

Comment: what did you try?? Post that

Comment: may be you must be getting error related to the button click now. As we have removed the view parameter, you must be getting exception something like nosuchmethod exception.

Comment: but are you getting some exception or no exception but notification is not getting displayed?

Comment: I am getting that no such method exception. I am trying to call this create notification method from inside another method as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void createNotification(View view) {

  showNotification("hello");
} 

public void showNotification(String msg)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText(msg).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original_logo)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok as I understand you don't want to have a method which has `View` as parameter, I looked at the code at [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html),

what I can tell you is this tutorial was made for learning so author wants you to get the feel how and when the Notification is made so he made a `clickListner` event which listens to the Button click which is being mentioned in the attribute `(android:onClick="createNotification")`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="createNotification"
    android:text="Create Notification" >
</Button>
```

That's why you have a method in your activity which requires you to take a `View` as parameter to run the code.

you can easily change that by having your button referenced thorough code Like this and off-cousre you may remove `android:onClick="createNotification"`

```
Button my_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
my_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Now call any method which you want here or
            makeNotification();
        }
    });

makeNotification(){

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

// Build notification
// Actions are just fake
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("content").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original_logo)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "Call", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "More", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "And more", pIntent).build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// hide the notification after its selected
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```